# Create array in a bunch of 5

Tags: php, arrays, sleep, chunks

I have 15 records, first 5 records  should iterate normally, after that all records should be at a gap of 2 seconds and in a bunch of 5 i.e basically I should have 3 sets of 5 records.So far I have tried :

```
    $flag = 0;
     foreach($db_array as $arr){ 
    if($flag>4) {
            sleep(2); 
     } 
   if($flag >= 15 ) 
     break;
 $flag++; 
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
A===07:17:38 
B===07:17:38 
C===07:17:38
D===07:17:38
E===07:17:38
F===07:17:38 
G===07:17:40 
H===07:17:42 
I===07:17:44 
J===07:17:46
K===07:17:48
L===07:17:50
M===07:17:52 
N===07:17:54 
O===07:17:56
P===07:17:58 07:18:00
```

Comment: Just go with `array_chunk`, and then use two nested loops to iterate over the result …?

Comment: I tried to split an array with array_chunk and then make a foreach inside foreach but seems I made some mistake,can you guide me with detail.

Comment: I don’t know what guidance you could need on something as simple as nesting two loops to iterate over a two-dimensional array. Show us what you tried instead, and describe what exactly the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
$flag = 0;
// Fake array, use your own DB array here
$db_array = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","Q","P","R"];
foreach($db_array as $arr){
    if($flag % 5 == 0) {
        sleep(2);
    }
    // Added print to show time
    print_r($arr." - ".date("Y.m.d H:i:s")."\n");
    $flag++;
    if($flag >= 15 )
        break;
}
```

And this will printout:

```
A - 2020.09.17 10:47:16
B - 2020.09.17 10:47:16
C - 2020.09.17 10:47:16
D - 2020.09.17 10:47:16
E - 2020.09.17 10:47:16
F - 2020.09.17 10:47:18
G - 2020.09.17 10:47:18
H - 2020.09.17 10:47:18
I - 2020.09.17 10:47:18
J - 2020.09.17 10:47:18
K - 2020.09.17 10:47:20
L - 2020.09.17 10:47:20
M - 2020.09.17 10:47:20
N - 2020.09.17 10:47:20
O - 2020.09.17 10:47:20
```

Basically,

```
if($flag>4) {
        sleep(2); 
 }
```

This check will sleep for 2s once flag is higher than 4, so also on 5, 6, 7...
So You need to check if flag is divisble with 5, and if so, add sleep.